# odbc connection string for microsoft sql server driver

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, utf-8, character-encoding, odbc

how to set utf8 chaset for this connection?
i use code below :

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<?php
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=MGHZA\MSSQLSERVER2012;      Database=test_db;", "sa", "mghza");
$query = "SELECT * FROM t1"; 
$res = odbc_exec($connection,$query); 

while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($res) ) { 
    print_r($row); 
} 
?>
```

and when i run the page , will see below text:

```
Array ( [id] => 2 [fname] => ���� [lname] => ����� )
```

i save persian characters in my database

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
 print_r(utf8_decode($row));
```

Comment: Page is in utf8 charset i try print_r(utf8_decode($row)); but not working